# Displaying HeatMap in DataGridView from List<List<T>> in C#

Tags: c#, heatmap

I've got some data in List of List of touples. My task is to make a heatmap from that.
Being newbie in C#, I've searched the net and found a way of solving this task by painting elements in DataGridView, but I don't understand, how to do it.
So,I've got a list of Touples:

```
 using SpikeDataPacket = List<Tuple<double, double>>;
```

This is the way I load data inside the grid:

```
public HeatForm(List<SpikeDataPacket> list)
{
  SpikeList = list;
  InitializeComponent();
  var bindstim = new BindingList<SpikeDataPacket>(SpikeList);
  var stimsource = new BindingSource(bindstim, null);
  heatMap.DataSource = stimsource;
}
```

But this displays a table with "capacity" and "count" inside the DataGridView, but not the data.
Also, I've found the way to count the color, but don't know, how to apply it:

```
private Color HeatMapColor(double value, double min, double max)
{
  Color firstColour = Color.RoyalBlue;
  Color secondColour = Color.LightSkyBlue;

  // Example: Take the RGB
  //135-206-250 // Light Sky Blue
  // 65-105-225 // Royal Blue
// 70-101-25 // Delta

int rOffset = Math.Max(firstColour.R, secondColour.R);
int gOffset = Math.Max(firstColour.G, secondColour.G);
int bOffset = Math.Max(firstColour.B, secondColour.B);

int deltaR = Math.Abs(firstColour.R - secondColour.R);
int deltaG = Math.Abs(firstColour.G - secondColour.G);
int deltaB = Math.Abs(firstColour.B - secondColour.B);

double val = (value - min) / (max - min);
int r = rOffset - Convert.ToByte(deltaR * (1 - val));
int g = gOffset - Convert.ToByte(deltaG * (1 - val));
int b = bOffset - Convert.ToByte(deltaB * (1 - val));        

  return Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you explain the input and the desired output a littel more detailed? What are those numbers in the tuples? How should the map look like?

Comment: @TaW, the map should look something like [this](http://matplotlib.org/_images/pcolormesh_levels.png). The first number in tuple is the time value, the second is the intenstity value.

Comment: So that will be a 1D  or a 2D map then?

Comment: @Taw, It should be 2D, because I've got several rows. Again, there is a list of  lists of tuples. Each list of tuples is like a row. As we have list of such rows, we'll have a 2D map. Sorry for my bad English and bad way of explanation.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I missed the list of list part. So we have an outer list mapping to rows, and inner list mapping to columns and tupels mapping to cells, right? The values map to colors. And the times, how to do they come in? Also: what do we know about the ranges of both values? And about the numbers of rows and columns? A lot of questions, I know, but they wil help to help. Please try to put it all into the question..

Comment: @TaW, Sorry for being such a bad question maker. So, every inner list is actually a set of graph coordinates. I used it to make graph, but my teacher asked to present it also as a heat map. So every inner list is the dependence of light emision of a certain organic cell from time (It is emitting light beacuse of a Ca Imaging). So x - is a time value and y - is the light intensity value. So, I've got 20 cells aka 20 lists of lists with coordinates. So i want each of lists to present as a row in heat map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I would tackle the problem somewhat differently.

- I would start **without** using `DataBinding`. Neither the List of List of Tuple structure nor the mapping of a double to a `Color` lends itself to well to `DataBinding`.
- I'm also not sure about your color mapping algorithm..

To fill the data into a DataGridView DGV I use a simple routine, which first prepares the DGV and then paints the Cells:

```
void fillData()
{
    int maxRow = data.Count;
    int maxCol = data[0].Count;
    double factor = 1.0;

    DGV.RowHeadersVisible = false;
    DGV.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
    DGV.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    DGV.AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
    DGV.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
    //..

    int rowHeight = DGV.ClientSize.Height / maxRow - 1;
    int colWidth = DGV.ClientSize.Width / maxCol - 1;

    for (int c = 0; c < maxRow; c++) DGV.Columns.Add(c.ToString(), "");
    for (int c = 0; c < maxRow; c++) DGV.Columns[c].Width = colWidth;
    DGV.Rows.Add(maxRow);
    for (int r = 0; r < maxRow; r++) DGV.Rows[r].Height = rowHeight;

    List<Color> baseColors = new List<Color>();  // create a color list
    baseColors.Add(Color.RoyalBlue);
    baseColors.Add(Color.LightSkyBlue);
    baseColors.Add(Color.LightGreen);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Yellow);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Orange);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Red);
    List<Color> colors = interpolateColors(baseColors, 1000);

    for (int r = 0; r < maxRow; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < maxRow; c++)
        {
            DGV[r,c].Style.BackColor = 
                           colors[ Convert.ToInt16( data[r][c].Item2 * factor)];

        }
    }

}
```

You would wnat to change a few things, especially the base colors and the number of colors you want to get, depending on your values but also the mapping from a double value to a integer index!

Here is the function to create a list of interpolated colors. It takes a few base colors and a length N and returns N interpolated colors. This makes the mapping simple and flexible..

```
List<Color> interpolateColors(List<Color> stopColors, int count)
{
    SortedDictionary<float, Color> gradient = new SortedDictionary<float, Color>();
    for (int i = 0; i < stopColors.Count; i++) 
        gradient.Add(1f * i / (stopColors.Count-1), stopColors[i]);
    List<Color> ColorList = new List<Color>();

    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(count, 1))
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        Rectangle bmpCRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
        LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush
                                (bmpCRect, Color.Empty, Color.Empty, 0, false);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
        cb.Positions = new float[gradient.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < gradient.Count; i++) 
            cb.Positions[i] = gradient.ElementAt(i).Key;
        cb.Colors = gradient.Values.ToArray();
        br.InterpolationColors = cb;
        G.FillRectangle(br, bmpCRect);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) ColorList.Add(bmp.GetPixel(i, 0));
        br.Dispose();
    }
    return ColorList;
}
```

My test data were created like this:

```
List<List<Tuple<double,double>>> data = new List<List<Tuple<double,double>>>();

Random R = new Random();

void createData(int maxRow, int maxCol)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < maxRow; c++)
    {
        data.Add(new List<Tuple<double, double>>());
        for (int r = 0; r < maxRow; r++)
        {
            data[c].Add(new Tuple<double, double>(c, Math.Min(999, R.Next(r*c))));
        }
    }
}
```

and I used it like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createData(40, 40);
    fillData();
}
```

Here is a (rather boring) screenshot:

[image: heat map]

Once you got the display as you want it, you may want to decide about going for a solution **with** `DataBinding`. I believe that you will need to use `OwnerDrawing` the `Cells`. Once you have the values in the cells you can use the same mapping simply like this:

```
private void DGV_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
   Color theColor = .....
   e.Graphics.Clear(colors[theColor]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a simple way to color items:

[image]

**Our object of reference:**

```
internal class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

**Usage:**

- paste the code and re-build your project
- go to Data Sources pane and create a new data source
- select that type of object and press Finish
- drop the created source to your from (it creates a `DataGridView`)

**Coloring the cells:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // create some items
        itemBindingSource.Add(new Item {Name = "name1", Value = 0});
        itemBindingSource.Add(new Item {Name = "name2", Value = 0.5});
        itemBindingSource.Add(new Item {Name = "name3", Value = 1});

        // find column index to color
        string columnName = "Value";
        int columnIndex = -1;
        DataGridViewColumnCollection columns = itemDataGridView.Columns;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.Count; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn column = columns[i];
            if (column.DataPropertyName == columnName)
            {
                columnIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        // color cells
        if (columnIndex >= 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in itemDataGridView.Rows)
            {
                if (!row.IsNewRow)
                {
                    // get associated data
                    var item = (Item) row.DataBoundItem;
                    // build color from associated data
                    Color fromArgb = Color.FromArgb((int) (item.Value*255), 128, 128);
                    row.Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = fromArgb;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Roll up your own coloring logic then,