# Binding list of lists to chart control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I'm working a windows form application that generates a heat map of data points.  I'm using a list of custom structures called "Pipes" that contain their own lists of data points.  I then iterate over my list of lists as shown here:

```
foreach (NewPipe pipe in wall)
{
    foreach (DataPoint x in pipe.returnPoints(xNum))
    {
       chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.Add(x);
    }
    xNum++;
}
```

While this works, it seems horribly inefficient.  Also it would be nice if I could just update my list of lists and have the graph update, instead of having to clear it and re-graph it (or manually delete the removed data and etc).  I'm familiar with the BindingList structure, is this the right tool to use and if so, how do you bind a list within a list to a chart?  (Since I'm really after the data stored in a list in the lower tier list).  Maybe I'm using the wrong structures entirely? (Though lists of lists actually matches how the data is generated fairly well).

Comment: What chart type do you use? It would help to understand the problem better to see what the result looks like.

Comment: Right now I'm just using a points chart, but I need to spend some time figuring out which style works best for a heat map.  I can post a screenshot of the current appearance once I'm back at my PC.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: @TaW, I got pulled off onto something else for the last couple weeks.  I'll accept your answer once I get back to this and give everything a try.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to create a [Heatmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map) which looks something like my examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415191/heatmap-style-gradients-in-net/30416635?s=1|3.7739#30416635) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461579/displaying-heatmap-in-datagridview-from-listlistt-in-c-sharp/26482670?s=3|1.8835#26482670) I'm afraid that using a `Chart` Control for this purpose may not be the best choice.

While it is not impossible to use a `Charttype Point` to create it, it will have several problems..

- Most notable is the fact that you will have to create individual `DataPoints` for each point in the map.
- These are rather expensive
- They will not resize with the chart. You can set their size by setting the `Series.MarkerSize` to a suitable number of pixels but you will have to adapt when you resize.
- One further limitation of this is that the markers all are squares, so it will be hard to create a gapless chart..

You have asked about `DataBinding` to make the whole thing more efficient.

You are using lists of list of `DataPoints` but:

- `DataBinding` only binds values to the chart, not ready-made `DataPoints`
- Even lists of values have their [limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd456766.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> When using non-tabular data sources such as lists, or arrays, you can
>   bind only Y values, regardless of the type of data-binding method
>   used. This is because columns cannot be specified for X values and
>   other chart properties, such as Tooltip.

This may not be a big problem if your X-Values are not important.

Well, there are [many ways](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx) to use `DataBinding` with a `Chart`, both at the `Chart` and at the `Series` levels.

And there is even one [Points.DataBind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd467642%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) overload  that [looks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx) as if it would be suitable to bind Colors as is supports extended properties:

> Points.DataBind
>
> Same as the above, plus:
>
> Supports binding for extended chart properties like tooltips.

So the binding to a `DataView`

```
DataTable DT = new DataTable("data");

DT.Columns.Add("xField", typeof(int));
DT.Columns.Add("yFields", typeof(int));
DT.Columns.Add("tipp", typeof(string));
DT.Columns.Add("kolor", typeof(Color));

DataRow row = DT.NewRow();
row["xField"] = 1; row["yFields"] = 1; row["tipp"] = "red"; row["kolor"] = Color.Red;
DT.Rows.Add(row); // ...etc...

DataView DV = new DataView(DT);
chart1.DataSource = DV;
```

should work like this:

```
someSeries.Points.DataBind(DV, "xField", "yFields",
                           "MarkerColor=kolor,Color=kolor,Tooltip=tipp,Label=tipp");
```

However, while the `Labels` and `ToolTips` do indeed get bound, the `DataPoint.Color` does not:

[image]

This is disappointing; after all the [DataPoint.Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcustomproperties.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is a `bindable` attribute. But it gets ignored.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx) is a list of supported properties:

> A list of these properties are as follows: AxisLabel, Tooltip, Label, 
>   LegendText,  LegendTooltip and CustomPropertyName (the name of a
>   custom property).

**Conclusion**: Afaik `DataBinding` will **not** let you set **colored** `DataPoints`. To make your code more effective using a `Chart` control, you can simply try using `chart1.SuspendLayout` and `chart1.ResumeLayout` to make the setup happen all in one.

**However I would instead consider not using a Chart control in the first place.**

The links to the two examples I gave in the first paragraph show two alternative ways:

- The first one is all about drawing the heatmap in GDI+. This is really trivial and very efficient. (The details in the post are probebly not pertinent to your problem..) For simple scaling I suggest drawing into a `Bitmap`, which you assign to a `Panel` or `PictureBox`; create it in the `ClientSize` and set the `Panel.ImageLayout` (or the `PictureBox.SizeMode`) as `Stretch`.
- The second example uses the `Cells` of a `DataGridView` as large 'pixels'  for the heatmap...

See the second link for a method to create a nice `List<Color>`!

Comment: Looks like some MS blockheads have killed the link to chart binding :-( - If anybody finds it I love to hear from you. Otherwise you will find it in the waybackmachine..