# Drawing a matrix with a gradient of colors "Spectrogram"

Tags: c#, audio, drawing, fft, spectrogram

After using STFT(Short-time Fourier transform) the output is a matrix that represents a 3d plot as though `(A[X, Y] = M)` A is the output matrix, X is the time , Y is the frequency, and the third dimension M is the amplitude illustrated by the intensity of the pixel color as in the following pictures:

[image: ###Spectrogram 1]

[Spectrogram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtWqb.jpg)

How do I draw the output matrix A with a gradient of colors like in the pictures in C#? 
 Is there a library that contains a spectrogram control for C#?

---

**Update:** 
After some modifications on the given algorithm I could draw the spectrogram, I didn't change the color palette except the first color changed to black but I don't know why it's very faded!

This one represents a sound saying

> Bye Bye

[Bye Bye Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCCvr.jpg)

And this one of a `pure sine wave` so it's almost the same frequency all the time

[Pure sine wave Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po1Re.jpg)

The output is accepted it represents the frequencies of the input signal as expected, but i think there is a way to make the spectrogram as well illustrated as the ones in the examples, could you please take a look at my code and suggest modifications?

This is the event handler:

```
private void SpectrogramButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Complex[][] SpectrogramData = Fourier_Transform.STFT(/*signal:*/ samples,  /*windowSize:*/ 512, /*hopSize:*/ 512);
    SpectrogramBox.Image = Spectrogram.DrawSpectrogram(SpectrogramData, /*Interpolation Factor:*/ 1000, /*Height:*/ 256);
}
```

And this one is the drawing function after my modifications:

```
public static Bitmap DrawSpectrogram(Complex[][] Data, int InterpolationFactor, int Height)
{
    // target size:
    Size sz = new Size(Data.GetLength(0), Height);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);

    // the data array:
    //double[,] data = new double[222, 222];

    // step sizes:
    float stepX = 1f * sz.Width / Data.GetLength(0);
    float stepY = 1f * sz.Height / Data[0].GetLength(0);

    // create a few stop colors:
    List<Color> baseColors = new List<Color>();  // create a color list
    baseColors.Add(Color.Black);
    baseColors.Add(Color.LightSkyBlue);
    baseColors.Add(Color.LightGreen);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Yellow);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Orange);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Red);


    // and the interpolate a larger number of grdient colors:
    List<Color> colors = interpolateColors(baseColors, InterpolationFactor);

    // a few boring test data
    //Random rnd = new Random(1);
    //for (int x = 0; x < data.GetLength(0); x++)
    //    for (int y = 0; y < data.GetLength(1); y++)
    //    {
    //        //data[x, y] = rnd.Next((int)(300 + Math.Sin(x * y / 999) * 200)) +
    //        //                rnd.Next(x + y + 111);
    //        data[x, y] = 0;
    //    }

    // now draw the data:
    float Max = Complex.Max(Data);
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        for (int x = 0; x < Data.GetLength(0); x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < Data[0].GetLength(0); y++)
            {
                int Val = (int)Math.Ceiling((Data[x][y].Magnitude / Max) * (InterpolationFactor - 1));
                using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors[(int)Val]))
                    G.FillRectangle(brush, x * stepX, (Data[0].GetLength(0) - y) * stepY, stepX, stepY);
            }

    // and display the result
    return bmp;
}
```

I don't really understand the `log` thing that you are talking about in your answers, I'm sorry for my little knowledge.

---

**Update:** 

This is the output after adding taking `log10` to the magnitudes (negative values neglected):

1. [This one of "Bye bye" from before:](http://soundbible.com/664-Bye-Bye-.html)

[image]

2. [A Shotgun Blast:](http://soundbible.com/1919-Shotgun-Blast.html)

[image]

3. [A Music Box:](http://soundbible.com/1619-Music-Box.html)

[image]

I Think this output is acceptable, it is different from the examples I brought in the beginning but I think it's better.

Comment: I'm a little tied up atm but will add a bit to my answer later to demonstrate using a logarithmic scale as it is usually necessary for sonic data.. But the first image looks pretty good imo, so you don't have a problem there. If you change the 1st color to black you probably should __insert a dark and a medium blue stop color__ after it, though. Do play around with the colors to get a feeling for them!! You can use any number of them.. Also: You need to know the range your values have! Is it the normal range of sonics (16-16k)? If so..

Comment: ..the direct mapping to the linear color list will not work well. The list is linear with only 1000 colors and even if you blow it up to 16k or 20k it will still not be right. Instead you need a logarithmic lookup into them..

Comment: Instead of using the `Magnitude` directly I made this `Val = 20d * Math.Log10(Data[x][y].Magnitude)` I don't know if that is what you mean, but I had to neglect all negative values which results from `Magnitude values < 1` which appears to be the very dark regions in the original Image, so I thought of mapping the whole range of values after the `log` to the range of colors I have, so I make sure that all values are displayed.

Comment: Sounds pretty much what I would have recommended. Did you include a few colors after the Black stopcolors? Feel free to post the current result!

Comment: Yes this is the list of colors right now:
            `baseColors.Add(Color.Black);
            baseColors.Add(Color.DarkBlue);
            baseColors.Add(Color.MediumBlue);
            baseColors.Add(Color.LightSkyBlue);
            baseColors.Add(Color.LightGreen);
            baseColors.Add(Color.Yellow);
            baseColors.Add(Color.Orange);
            baseColors.Add(Color.Red);`

Comment: Hm, I don't think this can be __quite__ right as in all images there is a broad gap in the middle.. I'll try to simulate some more and better testdata..

Comment: Hm, can you upload zipped fft data of, say 'byebye' to some free upload place? I have put the sound into Audition and looked at the [result](http://www.file-upload.net/download-11162582/FFF685.png.html). There is a gap there too, much smaller going from 7k-11k and the upper band shows from 11k-15k. Nothing above as is to be expected with mp3. so here is some work to do and a good start will be to add lables to the graph..

Comment: What do you mean by the fft data?, and about the labels, from my search I found an equation that gives the frequency value for each row in the matrix which is `fr = sampleRate / # samples` and then the frequency value `f` for the index or row `n` from the equation `f = n * fr` as you see it is related to the sample rate and the number of samples which changes from file to file, I don't know if it is right but I didn't try it,

Comment: Well, don't you store the FFT results (`Complex[][] SpectrogramData`) or do you always calculate them again? Serializing them should be rather .. Do they contain linear data, ie eg one row per Hz or are the data already in a logarithmic scheme, meaning the same numer of rows/frequencies per octave? Do have a close look at the 1st image and also the one in my link: The labels are not linear but logarithmic..

Comment: For every input audio file, I calculate the `SpectrogramData` from the beginning because it is always different data for each audio file, what i'm doing in my [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) function is that i'm windowing(segmenting) the samples into a known length segments, and for each segment I calculate the FFT data, each index in the `SpectrogramData` is the FFT data for a single segment, for example `SpectrogramData[0]` is the FFT data of the first segment, and so on.. this is all I did up untill now.

Comment: In the drawing part, every index in the `SpectrogramData` is a column in the bitmap.

Comment: Do you actually use the full Complex structure? If so how? Or do you only use the Real part. If, do you know what if anything is in the Imaginary part?

Comment: I use the Magnitude which is `sqrt(real*real + imaginary*imaginary)`, so I use both of the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Ah. Well, if you can change the data structure from a jagged array to a real 2d array `Complex[,] fftData` this would save the data: `void saveKs(string dataFile)
{  using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(dataFile, FileMode.Create)))    {  for (int y = 0; y < fftData.GetLength(0); y++)
       for (int x = 0; x < fftData.GetLength(1); x++)
         {    writer.Write((double)fftData[x, y].Real);
          writer.Write((double)fftData[x, y].Imaginary);
            }    }
}` Saving a jagged array is of course only a little harder.., but all rows do have the same length, right?

Comment: [Here is the data](http://en.file-upload.net/download-11164535/fftData.bin.html) but how are you going to read it without knowing the array lengths?

Comment: Ha, you are right. I guess storing them along with the data would have helped; it could be 352x256, but maybe you can tell me? It is time for bed here now, though.. Here is a routine to store a complex jagged array `Complex[][] fftDataJ ` :

Comment: `void saveJs(string dataFile)
{
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(dataFile, FileMode.Create)))
    {
        writer.Write((Int32)fftDataJ.GetLength(0));

        for (int y = 0; y < fftDataJ.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            writer.Write((Int32)fftDataJ[y].GetLength(0));
            for (int x = 0; x < fftDataJ[y].GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                writer.Write((double)fftDataJ[y][x].Real);
                writer.Write((double)fftDataJ[y][x].Imaginary);
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: ..and to read it back: `Complex[][] loadJs(string dataFile)
{  Complex[][] fftJ = null;    using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(dataFile, FileMode.Open)))    {   int l0 = reader.ReadInt32();
fftJ = new Complex[l0][];
for (int y = 0; y < fftJ.GetLength(0); y++)
{
int l1 = reader.ReadInt32();
fftJ[y] = new Complex[l1];
for (int x = 0; x < fftJ[y].GetLength(0); x++)
{
double r = reader.ReadDouble();
double i = reader.ReadDouble();
fftJ[y][x] = new Complex(r, i);
            }
        }
    }
    return fftJ;
}` (Pardon the formatting but comment can only be so long..)

Comment: Yes that's true, I saved the data using your new function. [Here](http://en.file-upload.net/download-11166938/fftData.bin.html) is the data returned from the STFT function in my code. Notice that the first dimension index in the array represents the column number in the graph, or in the bitmap I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no out of the box control I know of. There may well be outside libraries you can buy, of course, but shhh, you can't ask on SO about them..

In theory you could use, or I guess I should rather say *abuse* a `Chart` control for this. But since `DataPoints` are rather expensive objects, or at least more expensive than they look, this seems not advisable.

Instead you can simply draw the graph into a `Bitmap` yourself.

- Step one is to decide on a gradient of colors. See the [interpolateColors function here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461579/displaying-heatmap-in-datagridview-from-listlistt-in-c-sharp/26482670?s=3|1.8724#26482670) for an example of this!
- Then you would simply do a double loop over the data using `floats` for the step and pixel sizes and do a `Graphics.FillRectangle` there.

Here is a simple example using `GDI+` to create a `Bitmap`  and a `Winforms PictureBox` for display. It doesn't add any axes to the graphic and fills it completely.

It first creates a few sample data and a gradient wih `1000` colors. Then  it draws into a `Bitmap` and displays the result:

[image]

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // target size:
    Size sz = pictureBox1.ClientSize;
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sz.Width, sz.Height);

    // the data array:
    double[,] data = new double[222, 222];

    // step sizes:
    float stepX = 1f * sz.Width / data.GetLength(0);
    float stepY = 1f * sz.Height / data.GetLength(1);

    // create a few stop colors:
    List<Color> baseColors = new List<Color>();  // create a color list
    baseColors.Add(Color.RoyalBlue);
    baseColors.Add(Color.LightSkyBlue);
    baseColors.Add(Color.LightGreen);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Yellow);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Orange);
    baseColors.Add(Color.Red);
    // and the interpolate a larger number of grdient colors:
    List<Color> colors = interpolateColors(baseColors, 1000);

    // a few boring test data
    Random rnd = new Random(1);
    for (int x = 0; x < data.GetLength(0); x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < data.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        data[x, y] = rnd.Next( (int) (300 + Math.Sin(x * y / 999) * 200 )) +
                        rnd.Next(  x +  y + 111);
    }

    // now draw the data:
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    for (int x = 0; x < data.GetLength(0); x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < data.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(colors[(int)data[x, y]]))
                G.FillRectangle(brush, x * stepX, y * stepY, stepX, stepY);
        }

    // and display the result
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Here is the function from the link:

```
List<Color> interpolateColors(List<Color> stopColors, int count)
{
    SortedDictionary<float, Color> gradient = new SortedDictionary<float, Color>();
    for (int i = 0; i < stopColors.Count; i++)
        gradient.Add(1f * i / (stopColors.Count - 1), stopColors[i]);
    List<Color> ColorList = new List<Color>();

    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(count, 1))
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        Rectangle bmpCRect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);
        LinearGradientBrush br = new LinearGradientBrush
                                (bmpCRect, Color.Empty, Color.Empty, 0, false);
        ColorBlend cb = new ColorBlend();
        cb.Positions = new float[gradient.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < gradient.Count; i++)
            cb.Positions[i] = gradient.ElementAt(i).Key;
        cb.Colors = gradient.Values.ToArray();
        br.InterpolationColors = cb;
        G.FillRectangle(br, bmpCRect);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) ColorList.Add(bmp.GetPixel(i, 0));
        br.Dispose();
    }
    return ColorList;
}
```

You would probably want to draw axes with labels etc. You can use `Graphics.DrawString` or `TextRenderer.DrawText` to do so. Just leave enough space around the drawing area!

I used the data values cast to `int` as direct pointers into the color table.

Depending on your data you will need to scale them down or even use a log conversion. The first of your images show a *logarithmic* scale going from 100 to 20k, the second looks *linear* going from 0 to 100.

If you show us your data structure we can give you further hints how to adapt the code to use it..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bitmap as per the other answer.  It's also common to use a color lookup table to convert FFT log magnitude to the color to use for each pixel or small rectangle.

Comment: I don't understand the `log` part I'm using the magnitudes as it is, because some magnitudes are less than 1 which results in negative `log` and that's making a problem when drawing, can you please make it more clear?

Comment: Normally, one offsets and scales the log magnitude so that it's range fits the size of your coloring scheme lookup table (0-255 colors, etc.). But you do need to ignore magnitudes of zero before taking the log.  Instead set them to a value that indexes the bottom of your lookup table.  The Weber–Fechner human perception law is one reason for using the log in log magnitude.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example? maybe you can use my code samples added to my question's body to clarify it.