# How do I get an array of all Pens and Brushes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on an application which generates the representation of the Mandelbrot set. I already got it to work, see the image below, pretty cool stuff!

[image]

For the colors I'm using an array like this:

```
Pen[] pens = {
    Pens.Red,
    Pens.Green,
    Pens.Blue,
    Pens.Cyan,
    Pens.Magenta,
    Pens.Yellow
};
```

Further on in my code I'm using this array to fill in the pixels using the following snippet:

```
while(iteration > 6)
{
    iteration -= 6;
}

graphics.DrawRectangle(pens[iteration-1], rectangle);
```

This gives me the right color (you can see the color patern repeats over and over)

I want to give my code a wider color pallette and make use of **all** the `Brushes` and `Pens` available.

However, when we look at the Pens documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pens(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that the Pens class contains properties only.

How do I get an array of all these Pens without the need to declare it myself color by color? This would take up a huge chunck of code which in my eyes seems to be like it could be done easier. Thanks!

Comment: Start with `typeof(System.Drawing.Pens).GetProperties()`

Comment: For __really__ cool colors forget the ready-made Pen/Brushes and use your own! You can create them on the fly from any Colr you like or calculate with Color.FromArgb; or in this case cache them in a List<SolidBrush> or List<Pen>

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481172/drawing-a-matrix-with-a-gradient-of-colors-spectrogram/34481807#34481807) for a function that creates a nice gradient from a few stop colors! From the Color list you can then either pick one and create a Pen=newPen(colorList[index]) on the fly or cache a set of pens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stuartd mentioned, you will want to use Reflection to get these.

```
var pens = typeof(Pens).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                       .Select(p => p.GetValue(null))
                       .OfType<System.Drawing.Pen>()
                       .ToArray();
```

The above code will return you an array of Pen. Keep in mind, you will also get `Transparent` included which you may want to keep or remove.

The same code above will work if you swap Pen for Brush.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how things work.

Yes, there are a bunch of pre-defined pens which generally avoid programs having to create & destroy pens.  However, you can make pens of any color, not only the defined ones.  Thus there are 16 million possible pens (although I would be surprised if Windows didn't barf on an attempt to create that many.)

Getting all predefined pens won't get all possible pens.